# Can I use .NET SDK to create Azure Table datasource for Azure Search index?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I would like to configure datasource including ia. field mapping for json string containing collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can - get the latest Azure Search SDK from nuget.org and use [DataSource.AzureTableStorage method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.datasource#Microsoft_Azure_Search_Models_DataSource_AzureTableStorage_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Search_Models_DataDeletionDetectionPolicy_System_String_).

You no longer need to use field mappings to populate string collection fields - Azure Search will do this for you automatically as long as the strings are formatted as a JSON array of strings. However, should you need field mappings for other reasons, they are available as [FieldMappings property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.indexer#Microsoft_Azure_Search_Models_Indexer_FieldMappings) of [Indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.indexer) class.